# i^x+i^y... (x.y) pairs

Tags: number-theory

Question :" Find the number of ordered pairs $(x,y)$ with $1 \le x < y \le 100$ and $i^x+i^y$ is real."

My work so far:

I tried using casework on $x$ when taken mod 4 to get the following cases

$x \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, I got a total of 325 $(x,y)$ pairs.

$x \equiv 3 \pmod 4$, I got a total of 276 $(x,y)$ pairs.

$x \equiv 2,4 \pmod 4$, I got a total of 1225 $(x,y)$ pairs.

Can anybody check that my numbers are right?...

Comment: Isn't $1^x = 1$ for any complex number $x$?

Comment: I ran a quick python program and counted 3750 ordered pairs.

Comment: Also, there's a typo in your question. I assume you mean $i^x+i^y$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $i^x$ is either $i,-1,-i,$ or 1, $i^x+i^y$ will be real when either a) x and y are both even, or b) x and y are both odd, with $x\not\equiv y \ (\mod 4)$.
In the first case, there are $50\choose 2$ ways to select x and y; and in the second case, there are $25\times25$ ways to choose x and y, since there are 25 integers in $\{1,\cdots,100\}$ which are congruent to 1 (or respectively, to 3)
mod 4.  Therefore there should be 1850 such pairs.

I believe you should have 300 pairs when $x \equiv 3 \pmod 4$.

Comment: Well, if $x,y$ are distinguished, we have $50\times 50$ for the first case and $50\times 25$ for the second case, following your logic.. (That gives $50\times 75=3750$ pairs, as Julian's program calculated.)

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I took $50 \choose 2$ in the first case since $x<y$, and I took $25\times25$ in the second case since there are 25 choices for the number congruent to 1, 25 choices for the number congruent to 3, and then x is the smaller of the two.